# how to install Xacro for ros noetic

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros noetic full desktop version and still, it shows errors

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362846/how-to-install-xacro-for-ros-noetic/) by [harish556](https://answers.ros.org/users/60452/harish556/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2020-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ty using sudo apt install ros-noetic-xacro

---

Originally posted by [Alejoxbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/68092/alejoxbg/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1